# How to pass AJAX POST data to jQuery nyroModal?

Tags: ajax, post, nyromodal

Ealier I tried using same functionality with colobox but could not success, now I'm trying to use nyroModal and trying to send ajax data using post method with iframe. But its not going through. Here is the code which I have tried:

```
   var src = "this is test data';
   $.nmManual('try_python.php',{
      callbacks: {
           initFilters: function(nm) {
           nm.filters.push('link');
           nm.filters.push('iframe');
         },
         ajax:{data:'code='+src, type:"post"}
      }
   });
```

I'm able to open iframe and content from try_python.php is properly displayed in the frame but passed data is not accessible to try_python.php.

I will really appreciate you for any input in this regard.

Kind Regards

Mohtashim

Answer (score 0):

I could not success in posting my content using POST method but I found a workaround where did the following:

(a) Saved my content in a hidden <div id="source" style="display:none;">...</div>
(b) Access this content from the iframe window upon successful load using the following:

```
var code = window.parent.$("#source");
```

and this is what I wanted to have....May be it will help many others. If you find a solution to pass direct content using post method kindly share.